# Work, Energy on incline

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

While watching this lessons, I dont understand why the angle between Force MG and MGSin is 30? according to his drawing and my drawing it should be 60 degrees? Yet at 5minute 14 seconds in the video he uses 30? In fact uses 30 for everything involving an angle... I just dont see how that is 30.

[image]

Comment: θ is 30 degrees here, yes.

Comment: thanks! just making sure, I didnt think he was wrong but just checking.

Comment: I can't see on this picture where he used 30° wrongly. Yes, if your drawing is correct, then the angle between the $mg$ force and it's $mg\sin \theta$ component is 60°, but where does he use the angle between these? As far as I can see he only uses the angle $\theta$, which indeed is (given as) 30°.

Answer (score -1):

Since $mg$ is downward, we take 2 of its components: the one along the surface and the one perpendicular to it.

[image]

Comment: The angle between mg and mgsin(thita) is 60 degree and as cos(60) is equal to sin(30) the component is mgsin(30)